# Primefaces tabview events

Tags: jsf, events, primefaces

I'm migrating app from Primefaces 3.5 to last version, actually 6.2. I have a problem with events on close and on change tabs. I have dynamically created tabs.
On TabChangeEvent tabClientId is different than in UIComponent, but it still works and I can change correctly between tabs. Real problem is when I close tab, then in contextEvent I have tabClientId = [object Object] and tabIndex is null so app explodes here:

*int tabindex = Integer.parseInt(params.get(clientId + "_tabindex"));*

Someone knows how to fix this?

```
                <p:tabView var="tabview" value="#{tabBean.tabs}"
                       binding="#{tabBean.tabGlTabView}" id="panelGl"
                       widgetVar="panelGlJs" dynamic="true" styleClass="contentPanel"
                       activeIndex="#{tabBean.index}">
                <p:tab title="#{tab.title}"
                       closable="true">
                    <ui:include src="#{tabBean.tab}" />
                </p:tab>

                <p:ajax event="tabChange"
                        onstart="setActive()"
                        update="@(this)" />
                <p:ajax event="tabClose"
                        listener="#{tabBean.onTabClose}" />
            </p:tabView>
```

Comment: Should your `update="@(this)"` be `update="@this"`?  And you did not post the Java code for your tabBean.close() event.

Comment: Also I would clone this project: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test and create a small reproducible test case.  If you can reproduce it then I suggest reporting a bug on the PF GitHub page.

Comment: I do not attach Java code because it runs after TabViewRenderer so code for tabBean.close() is never started because app explode before.

Comment: Then you should at least post the code how you make the tabs dynamic. And [mcve] is always required and the best thing to do/create